# RecylerView Data Update Always Brings Focus to First Item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I got stuck on an issue when updating a `RecylerView` with a new `ArrayList` that includes an `EditText`.  Whenever the `RecylerView` is updated with the new the `ArrayList` the program always selects the `EditText` of the first item in the `RecyclerView`.

There are `Listeners` that call the update function below each time there is a change of focus.  So in other words, you can't effectively select any other `EditText` item in the `RecylerView` because when the first item loses focus, the `RecyclerView` updates with the new `ArrayList` and then automatically selects the `EditText` of the first item in the `RecyclerView`.

Is it a default that a `notifyDataSetChanged()` just automatically selects the first item?  Or perhaps because of some way I set up the adapter?

```
private void refreshRecyclerList() {

    // Set titles for the Recycler View Items
    textInputList.clear();
    textInputList.add(new EditTextRecyclerItem("Monthly on New Stuff", stringSpendingMonthly));
    textInputList.add(new EditTextRecyclerItem("Yearly on New Stuff", stringSpendingAnnually));

    //mAdapter.updateArrayList(textInputList);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I'm new to Android so please forgive if this is a simple fix that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

If you calling this `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` then it means whole recyclerview is refreshing, So if you want to focus on changed item `myAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position)` or `myAdapter.notifyItemChanged()` or you can scroll your RecyclerView by `recyclerview.scrollToPosition()`

Please try and revert me if it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I'm not sure how that could be implemented.  The notifier fires when the current item loses focus.  So it's easy to know the position of where the focus was, but not where it's going.